# Occasional "No connections are available" on startup

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

Sometimes when I first boot in to my Windows 7 (Home Premium SP1), I get a red "X" over the Wifi indicator in the status bar.

Hovering over the indicator shows the popup "Not connected. No connections are available."

If I then disable the "Wireless network connection" (Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6230) and re-enable it always connects immediately and all is well.

This seems to rule out hardware or driver issues. Any thoughts?

Comment: if you don't disable and re-enable, does the problem eventually go away or is that your only recourse?

Comment: It actually sounds exactly like an issue with the combination of hardware and driver. Whatever the hardware and driver do on boot-up sometimes brings up the Wifi correctly and sometimes doesn't, but whatever the hardware and driver do when you disable and re-enable works reliably. If you want the problem to go away when the machine boots up unattended, you might create a start-up script that disables the device, waits for a while, then re-enables the device.